# typescript in vue bind class type setting

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I use Vue3(vite) SFC, and here is my snippet code:

```
<button :class="{'button__active': checked === '1'}">1</button>
<button :class="{'button__active': checked === '2'}">2</button>
```

and the typescript has wrong message:

```
Type '{ button__active: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'string | boolean | undefined'。ts(2322)
```

I don't know how to handle this in , or can typescript skip  check, thanks?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little change in the syntax will help?

```
<button :class="{checked === '1' ? 'button__active': ''}">1</button>
<button :class="{checked === '2' ? 'button__active': ''}">2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work, I tried in the code snippet and it is working without any warnings/errors.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checked: '1'
  }
})
```

```css
.button__active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typescript/4.8.0-beta/typescript.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button :class="{'button__active': checked === '1'}">1</button>
  <button :class="{'button__active': checked === '2'}">2</button>
</div>
```